# Implementar una aplicación Symfony que esta en C9

Tags: symfony2, cloud9

soy nuevo en esto de PHP y Symfony, 
realicé una aplicación sencilla en cloud9 utilizando symfony 
y la verdad que no tengo idea de como implementarla en mi LAN para que sea accesible desde todas las PC.
Me gustaría que me guíen un poco de cuales son los pasos que debería seguir.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

1.Tenes que saber la ip local de la pc (llamemole ip_pc1) en la que tenes la app en symfony. Luego desde un navegador web (chrome, firefox, internet explorer) desde otra pc, ingresar la ip_pc1.

Todo esto funcionará si estás corriendo el servidor de base de datos y el servidor web en la computadora donde tenes la symfony app.

2. Si queres que las pc de tu LAN accedan a la symfony app subida en cloud9 vas a tener que usar la c9 público y no el privado porque sino siempre pedirá usuario y contraseña para ingresar a cloud9. Por otra parte, todas las PC de tu LAN, tendrán que tener acceso a internet para poder conectarse con la aplicación web.